# word boundary that rejects leading/end non-alphanumeric character

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric, word-boundary

Right now I'm learning regular expression on Java and I have a question about the word boundaries. So when I looking for word boundaries on Java Regular Expression, I got this \b that accepts word bordered by non-word character so this regex 
`\b123\b` 
will accepts this string `123 456` but will rejects `456123456`. Now I found that a condition like the word `!$@#@%123^^%$#` or `"123"` still got accepted by the regex above. Is there any word boundaries/pattern that rejects word that bordered by non-alphanumeric (except space) like the example above?

Comment: Under what condition do you want `123` to be accepted? `123` in `123 456` is bordered by non-alphanumeric also.

Comment: EDIT: I mean bordered by space so `456 123 456` still accepted but `654123789` will get rejected although it contains 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `\s` instead of `\b`.  That will look for a whitespace character rather than a word boundary.

If you want your first example of `123 456` to be a match, however, then you will also need to use anchors to accept `123` at the immediate start or end of the string.  This can be accomplished via `(\s|^)123(\s|$)`.  The carat `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: I tried on that but it returns no result at all with the same test case above

Comment: What do you mean by "no result at all"?  What is the actual code that you are invoking?

Comment: The expression has been fixed.  It was not correct to use a character class.  The character class made the matcher look for the characters ^ and $ rather than the anchors that were desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\S)123(?!\S)
```

`(?<!\S)` matches a position that is not *preceded* by a non-whitespace character.  (negative lookbehind)

`(?!\S)` matches a position that is not *followed* by a non-whitespace character.  (negative lookahead)

I know this seems gratuitously complicated, but that's because `\b` conceals a lot of complexity.  It's equivalent to this:

```
(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?=\w)(?<!\w)
```

...meaning a position that's *preceded* by a word character and not *followed* by one, or a position that's *followed* by a word character and not *preceded* by one.